# Cloud Firestore data at FullCalendar

Tags: html, angular, firebase, fullcalendar, google-cloud-firestore

### Can I use Observable with FullCalendar?

I would like to receive data from a collection I have in the Cloud Firestore and display these values ​​in real time in FullCalendar.

To do this I know I have to use an Observable, but I believe FullCalendar does not work with Observable.

Can I update real-time data in FullCalendar by receiving data from Cloud Firestore?

**component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

export interface Task {
  title: string;
  start: string;
  end: string;
  color: string;
}

@Component({
selector: 'app-component',
templateUrl: './app.component.html'})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private taskCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Task>;
  tasks: Observable<Task[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {

    this.taskCollection = this.afs.collection<Task>('task');
    this.tasks = this.taskCollection.snapshotChanges()
    .map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Task;
        return { ...data };
      })
    })
}

ngOnInit() {}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<p-schedule [events]="tasks" 
            [defaultView]="'agendaWeek'" 
            [selectable]="true" 
            [selectHelper]="true" 
            (select)="onSelect($event, modal)" 
            [allDaySlot]="false" 
            [droppable]="false" 
            [editable]="true" 
            [dragScroll]="false"
            [nowIndicator]="true" 
            (onEventClick)="onEventClick($event, modal)"
            [header]="headerConfig" 
            #fc></p-schedule>
```

### **With this the following error occurs:**

```
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:7492)
    at Schedule.ngDoCheck (schedule.js:231)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12365)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13886)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13829)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14722)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14663)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14648)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13795)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `tasks` is Observable, just try to add `async` pipe in your template:

```
<p-schedule [events]="tasks | async" 
            defaultView="agendaWeek" 
            [selectable]="true" 
            [selectHelper]="true" 
            (select)="onSelect($event, modal)" 
            [allDaySlot]="false" 
            [droppable]="false" 
            [editable]="true" 
            [dragScroll]="false"
            [nowIndicator]="true"   
            (onEventClick)="onEventClick($event, modal)"
            [header]="headerConfig" 
            #fc></p-schedule>
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was not possible!

Comment: was glad to help :) Actually, angular2 has very similar example: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#example-use